# The argument of the window function should be a constant for a partition?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The following SQL

```
with t as (
    select Id
    from IA
    INNER JOIN IAD ON IAD.PKEY = IA.DID
    LEFT JOIN  IAC ON IAC.INS = IA.INS
)
select Id,
       ntile((select count(*) from t) / 5000) over ( order by Id ) NT
from t;
```

got the following error when running in Oracle.

```
ORA-30488: argument should be a function of expressions in PARTITION BY
30488. 00000 -  "argument should be a function of expressions in PARTITION BY"
*Cause:    The argument of the window function should be a constant for
           a partition.
*Action:
Error at Line: 66 Column: 20
```

How to assign the parameter of `NTile` with computed value? I will need the code be able to be run in SQL Server via linked server.

```
-- SQL Server
select * from openquery(oracledb, '....the code above...')
```

Comment: I think it's yelling at you because you're trying to pass SQL Server syntax to an Oracle database. Your code works just fine in SQL, but I'm guessing it's not valid in Oracle, where you're remotely running it.

Comment: How to do it in Oracle?

Comment: Dunno. But I imagine Oracle has documentation around it, just like SQL Server does

Comment: I tried to search on it but cannot find anything. Not sure if it's hard to do this in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit strange requirement in function for "argument should be a function of expressions in PARTITION BY".
Something like that:

```
with t as (
     select Id, 
            trunc ( count(*) over ()  / 500) as cnt
       from IA
      INNER JOIN IAD ON IAD.PKEY = IA.DID
       LEFT JOIN IAC ON IAC.INS = IA.INS
 )
 select Id,
        ntile(cnt ) over (partition by cnt order by Id ) NT
 from t;
```

Comment: `cnt` will be all the same, but it still needs `partition by cnt` because of the Oracle syntax?

Comment: Yes. But honestly I do not know **why** it needs this expression in query partition clause. There will be only one partition.